# Rounding vector in pipe statement produces only returns 1st element in vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble that I have aggregated into means by group and wish to extract the max mean and min mean into a 2-element vector.

I also need to determine if the difference between the max and min is <= 1, then I need to round the vector to 3 digits, if not, then I can round to whole numbers.

For some reason when I do this in a pipe statement it is only returning the 1st element rounded. What is causing this behavior?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

tibble(x = runif(30, min = 205, max = 1440),
       y = rep(paste0("Group",1:5), each = 6)) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(x)) %>% 
  {c(min(.$mean), max(.$mean))} %>% 
  {ifelse(diff(.) <= 1, round(., digits = 2), round(., digits = 0))}
#> [1] 728

# Expected Behavior
c(728.0433, 1131.1561) %>% 
  round(digits = 0)
#> [1]  728 1131
```

Comment: `diff(.)` returns a length of 1 less than the original vector.

Comment: I understand that, but `.` should represent what is being piped in and not what is being forwarded from the conditional clause. Correct?

Comment: Before the last step, if you create an object `out` and then `diff(out)
[1] 227.9097`,   So, it is just length 1 instead of what you expect 2

Comment: I understand that `diff(.)` returns one number. But I'm not passing that number into `round()`. I'm passing what was piped before that into round.

Comment: `ifelse` requres all arguments to have the same length.  You can use `if/else`

Comment: Try `%>% {if(diff(.) <=1) round(., digits = 2) else round(., digits = 0) }`  (assuming length of initial vector is 2)

Answer (score 0):

You could do either:

```
tibble(x = runif(30, min = 205, max = 1440),
       y = rep(paste0("Group",1:5), each = 6)) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(x)) %>% 
  {c(min(.$mean), max(.$mean))} %>% 
  {ifelse(rep(diff(.) <= 1, 2), round(., digits = 2), round(., digits = 0))}
```

or

```
tibble(x = runif(30, min = 205, max = 1440),
       y = rep(paste0("Group",1:5), each = 6)) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(x)) %>% 
  {c(min(.$mean), max(.$mean))} %>% 
  {if(diff(.) <= 1) round(., digits = 2) else round(., digits = 0)}
```